# Is sound vibration height the same as saying sound vibration speed?

Tags: waves, acoustics

In a music book explaining the physics of sound he says exactly this:

> Page 12, Teoria da Música 5a Ed., Bohumil Med
>
> > Height - Denoted by the frequency of vibrations, that is, their speed. The higher the vibration speed, the acuter the sound. The unit of frequency per second is called Hertz (Hz).

When he says velocity I immediately associate the word "velocity" with the equation $v =λf$, but since the velocity of sound in air is constant to the same pressure and temperature conditions (which is the case of the medium where a musical note is produced) it does not It makes sense to speak of speed differences depending on the vibration, because if the vibration automatically increases, the wavelength drops, and in the end the speed of sound will always be the same... So, this is my question: does it make sense to attribute the word "velocity" to the concept of vibration? Is sound vibration height the same as saying sound vibration speed?

Comment: That vibrations may occur faster or slower is clear. The author says "vibration speed" not speed of the wave. But all seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Either the author or the translator has a terrible grasp of language.   I might rewrite as "Pitch - denoted by vibration frequency, that is, the number of cycles per second. The greater the frequency, the "higher" the pitch sounds to our ear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense within the context you are discussing - music. In music people often describe pitch as either higher (higher frequency) or lower (lower frequency), the frequency of the pitch is its height. The frequency can be represented by a metronome moving with a particular speed (i.e. a faster moving metronome has a higher frequency and vice-versa).

Using those terms, height is the same as vibration speed. Not the correct nomenclature in physics.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author describes the vibration frequency or pitch as the speed with which vibrations occur. Faster the vibrations, the higher the frequency. Height may be a description of shrillness. The vibration velocity in this context doesn't appear to describe the velocity of propagation of the wave.